# how do i reformat an unrecognized microSD card

Tags: micro-sd-card

i have tried to change my microSD card to a bootable nanoDLP for my pi.
but the card reader i used moved or something, and the process stop in an error, trying to reformat i put the microSD back to the PC, but it was not recognized and i got the "please insert a disk into usb drive" error.
i have tried to reformat by using the technique[in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/442912/how-do-i-reformat-an-unrecognized-flash-drive) or [in this guide](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-please-insert-a-disk-into-removable-disk/) and many other guides, that all show the same techniques.
non of this technique worked, all show as this disk is empty, and nothing is connected.
can i do something on the hardware level ? or any other techniques that i haven't tried ?

Comment: The best would be to replace the card and avoid doing again what killed the previous one. Mind you, the timing of its death might have been just a coincidence.

Comment: its kinda big card 128G so hopefully i can fix it, and in any case i ordered a small card but it will arrive with time.

Answer (score 0):

sdcard formatter (for Windows) is pretty good, it is worth trying.

https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/